# Quick Sort - How to apply recursive and get output

Tags: ruby, algorithm, quicksort

I am working on a school exercise on Quick Sort.
I have succeded to do the first exercise which is

> **Challenge**
> Given an array 'array' and a number 'p' in the first cell in the
> array, can you partition the array so that all elements greater than
> 'p' is to the right of it and all the numbers smaller than 'p' are to
> it's left? For example, if given the following as input:
>
> 4 5 3 9 1 The first number 4 is the pivot, so you should put the
> smaller numbers to the left, and the larger to the right, and output:
>
> 3 1 4 5 9 The array should otherwise remain in the same order.
>
> Can you write code to partition an array?
>
> Example p partition([4, 5, 3, 9, 1])
> => [3, 1, 4, 5, 9]

My code for the above in ruby is

```
def partition(array)
  # write your code here
  pivot = array.shift()
  base = [pivot]
  left = []
  right = []
  array.each { |e| if e < pivot
                  left.push(e)
               else
                  right.push(e)
               end
          }
  left + base + right
end

p partition([4, 5, 3, 9, 1])
# => [3, 1, 4, 5, 9]
```

The Challenge for which I am raising this Question is

[image]

The function should output like this

```
p some_function_name([5, 8, 1, 3, 7, 10, 2])
# => 2 3
#    1 2 3
#    7 8 10
#    1 2 3 5 7 8 10
```

I am trying for the last 36hrs how to apply the `partition` code above recursively on this challenge. During my 36hrs of research on the Quick Sort algorithm, I can make the code to give the result of a sorted array, but this challenge is asking to provide prints at certain conditions which I am not able to achieve.

Any help is much appreciated.

This one tried for pivot at end

```
def partition(array)
    # write your code here
    pivot = array[-1]
    i = -1
    j = 0
    while j < array.length-1
        if array[j] < pivot
            i += 1
            array[i], array[j] = array[j], array[i]
        end
        j += 1
    end
    array.insert(i+1, array.pop)
    puts index = i+1
    puts (array.take index).join(' ')
    puts (array.drop index+1).join(' ')
end

partition([5, 8, 1, 3, 7, 10, 2])
```

this one, I am not able to find a condition for terminating recursive function

```
def partition(array)
    # write your code here
    pivot = array.shift()
    base = [pivot]
    left = []
    right = []
    array.each { |e| if e < pivot
                    left.push(e)
                 else
                    right.push(e)
                 end
            }
    left + base + right
    if left.length < 2
      return
    end
    partition(left)
  end

p partition([5, 8, 1, 3, 7, 10, 2])
p partition([1, 3, 2])
p partition([8, 7, 10])
```

Comment: "I am not able to achieve" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: Can you show some results from your research? Even if your code isn’t working (yet) it probably helps to see what you’ve tried.

Comment: @Stefan I am trying different ways and seems the below code is what I am proceeding further

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9H8a7.png code available in original question now, I have edited the Question

Comment: "I am not able to find a condition for terminating recursive function" – There is no recursion in your code.

Comment: Code should be [edit]ed into the question--it's hard to read like this in the comments.

Comment: Thanks, then you can delete the comment to avoid confusion. `partition` needs to be called recursively on both halves and the line `left + base + right` does nothing when it's not the last line. Are you working from any pseudocode? I'd start with that and copy it. The base case should be the first thing you check in most recursive functions, directly on the parameter. If the subarray is small enough, stop, otherwise keep partitioning. Most quicksort functions use indices so you don't have to repeatedly copy the array which is expensive and unnecessary.

Comment: @ggorlen internet helped me a lot to code for quick sort to sort an array but the challenge here is about printing mulutiple lines when they met some condition which I am not able to understand and needs help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to my why you want `partition` to be recursive. There is no real natural way to make it recursive in a simple way. You can introduce a recursive *helper* method, but I don't see that as an improvement. `partition` really doesn't need to be more complicated than this:

```ruby
def partition(array, pivot)
  return [], [] if array.empty?

  array.partition(&pivot.method(:>))
end
```

If you absolutely must, you can make it recursive like this:

```ruby
def partition(...) = partition_rec(...)

private def partition_rec(array, pivot, left = [], right = [])
  return left, right if array.empty?

  first = array.first
  rest = array.drop(1)

  if first < pivot
    partition_rec(rest, pivot, left + [first], right)
  else
    partition_rec(rest, pivot, left, right + [first])
  end
end
```

With this `partition` in place, we can easily write our `quicksort`:

```ruby
def quicksort(array)
  return array if array.length < 2

  pivot = array.first
  left, right = partition(array.drop(1), pivot)

  quicksort(left) + [pivot] + quicksort(right)
end
```

Now, all we need to do is to also print the result at each recursive call. A simple way to do that would be with `Kernel#p`, which returns its argument, so we can just insert it without changing the return value:

```ruby
def quicksort(array)
  return array if array.length < 2

  pivot = array.first
  left, right = partition(array.drop(1), pivot)

  p quicksort(left) + [pivot] + quicksort(right)
end
```

If we need to replicate the *exact* format of the string as given in the question, then we should use `Kernel#puts` instead:

```ruby
def quicksort(array)
  return array if array.length < 2

  pivot = array.first
  left, right = partition(array.drop(1), pivot)

  (quicksort(left) + [pivot] + quicksort(right)).tap do |result|
    puts result.join(' ')
  end
end
```

Note that there is a *big* no-no in your code. Here, you are modifying the argument passed into `partition`:

> ```ruby
> array.shift()
> ```

Same here:

> ```ruby
> array.insert(i+1, array.pop)
> ```

You must not, ever, mutate an argument. In fact, you should avoid mutation *at all*, as much as possible. The only thing you are allowed to mutate is yourself, i.e. `self`. But even then, you should be careful.

Comment: You are fantastic, It worked like a magic when I run the code in my system. Thank you very much.